# Render PDF Error in Quarto - dvipdfmx:fatal: Unable to open

Tags: latex, r-markdown, quarto

I am using Quarto and trying to create a PDF. When I render the PDF for the first time everything is fine. However, when I made a change and tried to render the PDF a second time I got the following error:

> restricted \write18 enabled.
>
> entering extended mode
>
> dvipdfmx:fatal: Unable to open "AWS_Architecture.pdf".
>
> No output PDF file written.
>
> compilation failed- error

I have found that if I rename the .qmd file that fixes it, but that is not ideal (e.g. AWS_Architecture.qmd --> AWS_Architecture2.qmd). Even when I delete all of the files in the folder and start over using the same original name "AWS_Architecture.qmd", I still get the error and the PDF does not create.

Looking into the logs I found this.

> LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get
> cross-references right.
>
> Error 1 (driver return code) generating output; file
> AWS_Architecture.pdf may not be valid.

Below is the basic code for reference, nothing special.

```
---
title: "AWS Architecture"
format: pdf
---

## AWS Architecture 

![](images/AWSArchitecture.png)
```

Comment: are you sure your title isn't a type? you have `title: AWS Architecture"`, missing a `"`

Comment: Good catch. I made a small edit to the title before uploading the code snippet. The " was there in the original code.

Comment: What if you make a new project and copy and paste the file contents from the old to the new file, do you get the same error? also cleared R session history might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the error was arising because I was working out of Google Drive for desktop folder. This error does not occur when the working directory is set to a local folder on the PC.